# can't install ubuntu 12.04 64-bit in VMware or Virtualbox on windows 7 64-bit system

Tags: 64-bit, virtualbox, vmware

I need help!  I just got a new 64-bit system and want to run Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit in VMware or Virtualbox, not sure the difference between the two so doesn't matter there.  Anyway, I had no problems installing Ubuntu 32-bit in VMware.  Runs fine but wan't to try the 64-bit to see if it's noticeably faster.  I've tried in both VMware and Virtualbox using CD, DVD, USB and .iso but all seem to freeze up during install.  I've waited upwards of 4 hours to see what happens, maybe more.

Does anyone out there have any ideas what's going wrong?  Is it possible that I'm downloading corrupted iso from Ubuntu download site?  I've downloaded a few different times but makes no difference.  Please help!  I'm really anxious to see what this new machine can do.

Comment: If it took 5 hours that means VMware/Virtualbox is using software emulation. Everything else will also be very slow. Make sure you enable VT in your BIOS settings.

Answer (score 1):

As OP mentioned:

> I was finally able to install using the DVD iso but had to be very,
>   very patient.  It completed after almost 5 hours or so!  But, I'm
>   thankful to finally be able to run it!